# In javascript, how would I do this rfind?

Tags: javascript, python

```
www.mydomain.com/invite/abc123
```

I want the function to return "abc123". The logic goes like this:

```
If there is a forward slash, then take all characters after the last forward slash.
```

In python, I write it like this:

```
if s.find('/') >= 0:
    return s[s.rfind('/')+1:]
```

But how do I do this in javascript?

Comment: In Python, why don't you just do, `s.split('/')[-1]` rather than perform each of those iterations over the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need regexp to do this.

```
var s = "www.mydomain.com/invite/abc123";

if(s.indexOf("/")>=0)
    alert(s.split("/").pop());
```

Answer (score 10):

You can just say

```
s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("/"))
```

Returns the whole string if `s` has no slashes!